# Что за стиль конкатенации? "xxx""xxx"

Tags: c++, c

```
const char* a = "3""3";
cout << a << endl; //33
```

Что это за стиль такой,впервые увидел.Почему так можно и что происходит при такой конкатенации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Получится один строковый литерал. `"a""b"` означает то же, что и `"ab"` для программиста, потому что конкатенация происходит после препроцессинга, но до непосредственно компиляции, так что на этап, ответственный за появление translation unit, придёт один и тот же литерал.

Обычно это используют для длинных литералов, которые не умещаются в ограничение на длину строки IDE, либо для логического структурирования кода.

Comment: а это примечательность появилась в си или c++?

Comment: @Whitehorse в C

Comment: а как этот прием называется?

Comment: @Whitehorse смежные строковые литералы, их превращение в один -- конкатенация